# How Customize Component Label in ZK

Tags: java, zk

Haii all i need help, i want to custom Label component in zk and i nedd to add a property wich is mandatory property when i set mandatory="true" the asterix symbol will be appear and if i set mandatory="false" the asterix symbol disappear,and i am trying like this :

```
private Label label;
    private Label sign;
    private String lblValue;
    private String REQUIRED_SIGN = " *";
    private boolean mandatory;


    public SignLabelCustom() 
        {
        label = new Label();
        label.setSclass("form-label");
        appendChild(label);
        sign = new Label();
        if(mandatory=true){
         sign.setValue(REQUIRED_SIGN);   
         sign.setStyle("color: red");
         appendChild(sign); 
        }
        else{
         sign.setValue("");   
         sign.setStyle("color: red");
        removeChild(sign); 
        }

    }

    public String getValue() {
        return lblValue;
    }

    public boolean isMandatory() {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory(boolean mandatory) {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }



    public void setValue(String lblValue) {
        label.setValue(lblValue);
        this.lblValue = lblValue;
    }
```

but the condition does'nt working, how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is called an HtmlMacroComponent, which combines a label and a textbox...

You start with a zul file:

```
<zk>
<label id="mcLabel"/><textbox id="mcTextbox"/>
</zk>
```

...and create a component for it...

```
public class MyTextbox extends HtmlMacroComponent {

    @Wire("#mcTextbox")
    private Textbox textbox;

    @Wire("#mcLabel")
    private Label label;

    private String caption;

    private boolean mandatory;

    public MyTextbox() {
        compose(); // this wires the whole thing
    }

    public void setMandatory(final boolean value) {
        mandatory = value;
        updateCaption();
    }

    public boolean isMandatory() {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setCaption(final String value) {
        caption = value;
        updateCaption();
    }

    public String getCaption() {
        return caption;
    }

    protected void updateCaption() {
        label.setValue(mandatory ? caption + "*" : caption);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return textbox.getValue();
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        textbox.setValue(value);
    }

}
```

...and now you can use it, for example by defining it on the top of your zul file... (adjust package and .zul name as required):

```
<?component name="mytextbox" macroURI="/zk/textbox.zul" class="com.example.MyTextbox"?>
```

...so you can simply use it...

```
<mytextbox id="name" value="Frank N. Furter" caption="Your name" mandatory="true"/>
```

Later you can define a language addon for it...

my-language-addon
    xul/html
    
        mytextbox
        com.example.MyTextbox
        /zk/textbox.zul

...so that you don't need to put the definition on top of every .zul file where you use it anymore. See the [documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Development_Essentials/Creating_the_Configuration_Files/The_language-addon) for more on this.

Of course, you also could only create a new label, etc. but I found it's a good think to create MacroComponents for those jobs that combine various components, since this way, for example, you could also automatically add validation, etc.

Comment: sorry for late reply, if i flowoing your suggest it mean i must adding addon tag in my zk.xml, and i  don't need to put the definition on top of every .zul file like this example : `<?component name="signLabel" class="com.common.shared.acction.adira.bitozen.zul.SignLabel"?>` but if i prefer to adding the tag above should i need to adding tag addon in my zk.xml?

Comment: If you have no problem adding this tag to the .zul files in which you need it, you can of course do so. In this case, no further action needs to be done, no language addon needed. Mostly a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: okay now i will try to adding your example class `MyTextbox` into my project , and i will try to import in my zul like this `<?component name="mytextbox"  class="com.example.MyTextbox"?>` without `macroURI="/zk/textbox.zul"` because  i am not create any file to define addon, and i can use the component in my zul file like this `<mytextbox id="name" value="Frank N. Furter" caption="Your name" mandatory="true"/>' it should be working right? i just need to create one java class wich is `MyTextbox` and call it in zul file

Comment: If you don't define a zul file, your macro component will not have any content. You would have to create the content in the java class, then it could probably work.